# Video playback issues after the latest Chrome 108.0.5359.94 update

Tags: google-chrome, video

After the latest **Chrome 108.0.5359.94** update, some videos look like the image below during playback whereas some other videos play fine. In **Chrome 107** all videos were playing fine.

I am using **Xubuntu 22.04.1**, the kernel version is **5.15.0-56** and the video adapter is **Intel Iris XE Graphics**.

[image]

**Update 1:**
The problem remains even after the later **108.0.5359.98** update.

**Update 2:**
The problem is fixed after the newer **108.0.5359.124** update. They switched off *Hardware accelerated* Video Decoding. It's back to *Software acceleration* again.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behavior after the latest chrome update on pop-os with kernel 6.0.6.
When playing a YouTube video I am seeing the same issue, mostly when playing 1080p video layer.
Manually selecting another layer (e.g. 720p) sometimes play correctly.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I received two more Chrome updates but they didn't fix this. They patched other security issues. I have sent the issue to Google using Chrome's **Report Issue** menu option. Do you think you can send it too? More reports may speed up the fix. Who knows?!

Comment: Yes I also submitted the issue to Google.

Comment: This is not really an answer, should rather be a comment under OP's post.

Comment: @Vasilisa Agreed, but I couldn't add comment because of reputation check.

Comment: *user2276975*, the new **108.0.5359.124** update plays the videos correctly but they're software accelerated now.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Lubuntu 18.04 with Chromium 110 on a very old laptop (2012), and this helped :

- Install mesa-va-drivers
- Open /usr/share/applications chromium-browser .desktop file (different name depending on distro language)
- Change the exec line to :

  chromium-browser --use-gl=desktop

Now I can play Youtube 1080 60fps videos without stuttering.